# Scraping an element as it is stored in the database

Tags: web-scraping

I'm in the process of scraping a website using python with scrapy for a univeristy assignment.
I came across an element on the website taht's supposed to hold a rating. The rating is shown as an integer, but I think it's stored as a decimal in the database.

Is there a way to get the rating as it's stored in the database? if so, what are the tools and concepts I need to learn to do it?

An example for a page I'm trying to scrape: https://www.old-games.org/games/bond (written in Hebrew).
That's the element I'm talking about:
[rating element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh8cM.png)
and that's the html code:

```
<td class="game_specs">7/10</td>
```

The desired result is to get the actual value of "7" as it stored in the database, for example "7.32".
The website doesn't have an API for getting the information out of it.

I've tried to search on my own, but since I'm new to the field of web development/scraping I couldn't find any solution (probably because I don't know the terminology).

Comment: if the site doesn't have an API other than HTML, then you need access to the database. 
maybe contact the owner/administrator for either direct or api access?

Comment: "Is there a way to get the rating as it's stored in the database?"  No.  Why does it matter to you?

Comment: @Andy Lester , I intened to use those values for some computations, so I prefered them to be more accurate. I get that this is what i got to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're scraping a website, you can't even know *if* there is a database, let alone what's in the database. For all you (or your code) can tell, there is someone sitting there typing out those ratings manually, or a function that generates them at random each time you access the page.

Another way of looking at it is if I asked *you* to tell me what the "real" rating was, where would you look? You can look on the displayed page; you can look in the HTML source, and in any JS, AJAX calls, etc. If you can find it in any of those, you can write a scraper for it; if you can't, you can't.

Imagine for a second that there *was* a special trick to read the database of any website in the world. Now you could go to Amazon and apply that trick to find the personal details of the people who left reviews, or of the suppliers who are selling marketplace items!

The owner of any website can choose what information to give you, and what to keep private. There's no way to force the website to tell you the private bits unless the person operating the site has *accidentally* left something available publicly that they *intended* to be private (and looking too hard for those mistakes may well be breaking the law).

Comment: let me see if I understand you corect: If I disable javascript on chrome-dev-tools, then load the page again and all the data I need is still there - that means that there's no possible way to know what is stored in the database, right?

Comment: @Benny Well, it's hard to prove a negative: it might be on a different page, or in a different bit of the code, but whether it is or not is up to the operator of the site, not up to you. You can't force Amazon to tell you my e-mail address, all you can do is hunt around to see if they've exposed it somewhere.